# Polaroid Tiles For Navbar

Tags: html, css

2 Questions,So i want to create this navbar,i found this example on the net.The way the code is now when i add more li's they wrap to a second line why?.

Main question - I want to add more li's for the navbar, It's using the nth-child to target each li to style,i want it changed so that each li has a specific class so that i can add more li's and style each that way,and not use the nth-child.I tried it and couldn't get them to style to the way they look before the code changes,they instead just line up.

PS: Why is the `wrapper` doing this in this editor, but on my editor and browser is is working as expected.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px; 
}

#wrapper{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 padding: 30px;
 width:940px;
 border: 15px solid #B4D8E7;
 border-radius: 10px;
}


/*---2 Column-Right Layout----------------------*/ 
.layout-two-column-right #alpha { width: 650px; }
.layout-two-column-right #beta { width: 310px; }


ul.polaroids-menu { 
 width: 280px; 
 margin: 30px 0 18px -55px;
 list-style-type: none;
 }

ul.polaroids-menu a, ul.polaroids-menu a:hover { 
 display: inline;
 float: left; 
 width: auto;
 margin: 0 0 27px 30px; 
 padding: 6px 6px 3px; 
 background: #fff; 
 font-family: "Marker Felt", sans-serif; 
 text-align: center; 
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: #333; 
 font-size: 14px; 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25); 
 /* default/first image rotation */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg); 
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s linear; 
 }

ul.polaroids-menu img { 
 display: block; 
 width: 80px; 
 margin-bottom: 6px; 
 border-radius: 0; 
 border: 0;
 }

ul.polaroids-menu a:after { content: attr(title); }

/* #2 About Me */  
ul.polaroids-menu li:nth-child(2n) a { 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);  
 -moz-transform: rotate(6deg); 
 margin-left: -8px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }

/* #3 My Shop */
ul.polaroids-menu li:nth-child(3n) a { 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); 
 margin-top: -175px; 
 margin-left: 185px; 
 }

/* Scale the images on hover, add transitions for smoothing things out, and ensure the hover appears on top */  
ul.polaroids-menu li a:hover { 
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); 
 -moz-transform: scale(1.25); 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
 position: relative; 
 z-index: 5; 
 }
```

```html
<Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   
<head>
    <title>polaroids</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
     <ul class="polaroids-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com" title="My Family"><img src="http://themes.typepad.com/images/polaroid-myfamily.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com" title="About Me"><img src="http://themes.typepad.com/images/polaroid-aboutme.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com" title="My Shop"><img src="http://themes.typepad.com/images/polaroid-myshop.jpg" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being inserted on second line because `width` of `ul.polaroids-menu` is 280px where as each `image width` in list item is 80px with margins included calculated width comes out to `280px`. If you are adding additional list items I would suggest considering widths and margins for calculating width of parent container.

Also to assign specific css to each list item you could use specific child selector in css.

For additional 4th Link:

```
ul.polaroids-menu li:nth-child(4) a { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(6deg); -moz-transform: rotate(6deg); 
margin-top: -155px; 
margin-left: 275px; 
}
```

Notice the properties `margin-top` and `margin-left` it will be different for each link images.

Similarly you could add 5th image link to list and add relevant css for it. You could choose to tilt the image with `-moz-transform`and -webkit-transformrotate`angle property and update the`margin-left`value considering each image is of`width:80px`

I have not done exact calculations of widths for images including margins. But it should provide you sufficient idea on how to work around it. basic is each image is 80px so for 4 images parent container should have `320px' minimum width. You could use dev tools to see how margin plays out to get to exact number. Or you should calculate through css code.

**Update**
`ul.polaroids-menu li:nth-child(2n) a` css selector targets all even (multiple of 2's) `li` `a` children of `ul` and `ul.polaroids-menu li:nth-child(3n) a` css selector targets all odd (multiples of 3).

**Why would you need specific child css selector** 
Your requirement is to align all images in single row.

`margin-left` is primarily used to space images accordingly. Eventually with specific child css selector you could specify required left margin for each image along with inclination of image clockwise or anticlockwise.

That also means you can not use (2n) and (3n) in your case. Because it will apply exact same `margin-left` value to all even and odd numbered children. It might result undesired outcome.

**Why CSS works in case of you example?** Since there are only 3 images (2n) css is applied to only 2nd image and (3n) css gets applied to 3rd image only. 1st image is not effected by any of it. But as soon as you add 4th image (2n) property get applied to 4th image with same left margin hence undesired outcome.

**To make wrapper work properly** Add below css property.

```
html , body 
{
height : 100%;
}
```

**Working example JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/behc9zoj/

I hope it helps you clear your understanding.

Comment: I didn't understand the li:nth-child(2n).. The (2n) i have to check out how hat works,hence why i wanted to rather specify each li to a seperate class. I see u simply use number"2" and "3" to target the li in the order of the list,i get it that way,just didn't get the the way they did it. And the wrapper any idea why it is working in my browser and not here.

Comment: @Dev-88 What is wrong with `wrapper`? Could you update your question with screenshot of wrapper behavior on your browser? Kindly mention what browser you are using? I tested on chrome. I have updated answer with (2n) and (3n) behavior. I mentioned why you need particular css selector for child more than 3 but may be that was not clear earlier. Updated part would answer your query.

Comment: i understood. The wrapper i tested in chrome also,it worked, i meant why its not not working in this editor and in jsfiddle,but no worries about that. How would i center the UL in the wrapper when each li has its own specific margins now

Comment: I didnt follow you. What do you mean it is not working? What is your expected outcome ? Could you attach a screenshot of what you mean working and not working? It is working fine for me on this editor/jsfiddle.

Comment: No worries,it was the wrapper,it didn't expand in full height. The width was fine. Not sure why its working in your jsfiddle. But in mine it still doesn't expand. But in my project folder and browser it works 100% so i'm not worried

Comment: You should have mentioned that earlier. (problem with height of wrapper) Find updated answer. All you have to do is specify height of `html` and `body`. Lmk if it works finally without any issues. Upvote and accept. Tnx

Comment: Working here now,it did work on my project the way it was,that's why i found it odd. I see u put height in the body as well. Thanks for the help